# Fetch from database one use many times

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I would like to fetch a number of records from a database to fill a DropDownList that is filled in a OnItemDataBound of a DataList.

I think it might be a bit much to fetch all the records every time a DropDownList is bound since they are the same.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you could put your drop down list into a user control, and then output cache it, which would mean the resulting drop down list would not keep making new requests to the database each time it is loaded.

MSDN has quite a good article on output caching:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hdxfb6cy.aspx